# Character encoding in JSP input form

Tags: java, jsp, input

I would like to use hungarian character (ő,ű) in JSP input field, but i can not get these character from the JSP input (I use spring mvc), I get only õ,û from the input.

`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-2"%>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-2"); %>

<% response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-2"); %>`

....

```
    `<spring:bind path="city">
        <div>
            <form:input type="text" path="city" accept-charset="ISO-8859-2"></form:input>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>`
```

Comment: Maybe you should try Unicode encoding?

Comment: u mean (ő,ű) is converted to ( õ,û)?

Comment: Yes  (ő,ű) is converted to ( õ,û).
I tried to use the UTF-8, but it is not contain these characters.

Comment: I was wrong, UTF-8 contain these character.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.
I had to insert encoding filter to the web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```